# Load three images in three different picture box using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, image, picturebox

I have a Wikipedia API through which I can extract three images from Wikipedia page. I want to show these 3 images in three PictureBoxes. But I really do not know how to make a for loop to show three images in three different PictureBoxes. Here is my code

```
class Image
{
    public static PictureBox Image1 = new PictureBox();
    public static PictureBox Image2 = new PictureBox();
    public static PictureBox Image3 = new PictureBox();


    public static void Load_Image1()
    {
        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=400&titles=File%3ALuftbild%20Flensburg%20Schleswig-Holstein%20Zentrum%20Stadthafen%20Foto%202012%20Wolfgang%20Pehlemann%20Steinberg-Ostsee%20IMG%206187.jpg%7CFile%3AHafen%20St%20Marien%20Flensburg2007.jpg%7CFile%3ANordertor%20im%20Schnee%20(Flensburg%2C%20Januar%202014).JPG");
            var response = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
            var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Pageval> entry in responseJson.query.pages)
            {
                var url = entry.Value.imageinfo.First().thumburl;
                for(int i; i<=3 ;i++)
                {

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to load picture from `var url` to PictureBox. If that's the case, you can make an array or list of PictureBoxes and than loop that list (or array). So:

```
class Image
{
    public static PictureBox Image1 = new PictureBox();
    public static PictureBox Image2 = new PictureBox();
    public static PictureBox Image3 = new PictureBox();

    public static void Load_Image1()
    {
        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
        pictureBoxes.Add(Image1);
        pictureBoxes.Add(Image2);
        pictureBoxes.Add(Image3);

        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=400&titles=File%3ALuftbild%20Flensburg%20Schleswig-Holstein%20Zentrum%20Stadthafen%20Foto%202012%20Wolfgang%20Pehlemann%20Steinberg-Ostsee%20IMG%206187.jpg%7CFile%3AHafen%20St%20Marien%20Flensburg2007.jpg%7CFile%3ANordertor%20im%20Schnee%20(Flensburg%2C%20Januar%202014).JPG");
            var response = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
            var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

            List<string> urls = new List<string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Pageval> entry in responseJson.query.pages)
            {
                var url = entry.Value.imageinfo.First().thumburl;
                urls.Add(url);                        
            }
            // if you're sure that you're getting always at least 3 images, this will work
            for(int i = 0; i < pictureBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                pictureBoxes[i].Load(urls[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am gerring error for this line pictureBoxes.Get(i).Load(url); it shows Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox>' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox> @Misa_Lazoic

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer. In C# you access element of list using `[` and `]` brackets.
Java habits... :D

Comment: Hi. with this code I get same picture in three picturebox. But I need three picture in three picturebox. I thing the url should be varied also in  this code. because through the api I request 3 picture. @Misa

Comment: @user3193794 There. I added URLs to separate list, and then basically read element from one list and assigned value to corresponding element of other

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now it is working perfectly. @Misa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97728/discussion-between-user3193794-and-misa-lazovic).